# I want to refresh my report based on my speech is it possible in Power BI?

Tags: python, powerbi

Can we pass dynamic text value into power Bi. That dynamic value we would get from speech to text recognition.Please suggest how to pass this value into my report, it will refresh based on that value/ text ex:( 22-02-2020) then I will see Feb 22nd only

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in Power BI. Something like this would be an [accessibility feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-accessibility-consuming-tools), these are limited to high contrast visuals etc.
It would be possible to use the [Q&A feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-q-and-a) in Power BI, but you would have to capture the speech then covert it to text, then copy the text into the Q&A box